# Sharepoint workflow and wait for external event?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

In sp workflows, I use to subscribe for events, but all of them are sharepoint related. Is there any way to subscribe to external events ?

In my case, I have to start a job on an external web application (no relation with SP) and wait for its completion (several minutes later) before resuming the workflow.

What is the best way to reach my goal ? Can I use standard workflow foundation external events in sharepoint (and in this case, where can I register my external system?) ?

PS: I'm also the builder of the external application (at least in this case), so I can adapt this application if needed.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discover lately that the [pluggable workflow service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538619.aspx) is designed for such tasks.